# error C2552: 'pairs' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list

Tags: c++, std

How do I fix this to get this to compile?

```
#include <utility>

int main() {
    const std::pair<const char*, const char*> pairs[] = { {"String A", "String 1"}, 
                                                          {"String B", "String 2"} 
    }; 

}
```

Giving this compiler error:

```
1>main.cpp(256): error C2552: 'pairs' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
1>          'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' : Types with user defined constructors are not aggregate
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const char *,
1>              _Ty2=const char *
1>          ]
1>main.cpp(257): error C2552: 'pairs' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
1>          'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' : Types with user defined constructors are not aggregate
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const char *,
1>              _Ty2=const char *
1>          ]
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you run?

Comment: const std::pair<const char*, const char*> pairs[] = { make_pair("String A", "String 1"), 
                                                          make_pair("String B", "String 2") 
    };

Comment: @JoachimPileborg vs 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is [*uniform initialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) which was introduced in C++11. The C++11 compatibility in VS2012 is minimal at best, and missing completely in many areas.

You simply can't use a syntax like that using that version of Visual Studio. Instead you have to use e.g. [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair):

```
const std::pair<const char*, const char*> pairs[] = {
    std::make_pair("String A", "String 1"),
    std::make_pair("String B", "String 2")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu g++ 4.9.2 it works fine.
Don`t know for sure about Visual Studio 2012.
But first variant is that you need to use a constructor, and a second this feature is added in VS2013(bracket initialization).